# Box in css3 background gradient or table with pictures? I need to recreate this box, please suggest me

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to recreate the menu on the right of this page: http://www.bandbw.co.uk/properties/chateau-de-la-cazine/index.html (The resort-the investment-location etc...).

What do you thing the best way could be?
Css3 gradient (doesn't work on ie)
Table with images (I would like to do it with css)
Background image, then strech it with background-size? (corners will be deformed).

Please help me, i'm stucked.
Thanks

Comment: background-color, border-radius, border and an inset shadow. And it won't work in IE8 and below.

Comment: Though you could use PIE for IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need gradient its only one color just put border radius and you are good to go

Comment: well if you so badly want a gradient you must add it as a image background. Anyway the menu that you describe in your comment is only one color and its #F3F7F7

Comment: I don't want it so badly as my boss :/